# Using android Intent in adobe air

Tags: android, android-intent, air, barcode, zxing

it has been a while since I was here.

Currently, I'm trying to develop an application in Adobe AIR that has a 1D bar-code reader using the device camera function. I have tried using ZXing's library and followed http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-a-qr-code-reader-in-flex-on-android example. The QR reads fine however, I can't managed to get 1 D bar-code reader to work. Even with MultiFormatReader class.

Nevertheless, I tried ZXing's BarcodeScanner from Android Market and it works just fine on my device. So, I have been thinking of using ZXing's android Intent to handle the reading and pass the result back to my AIR application instead. But, I don't know how to launch android intent from AIR.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm still waiting if anyone knows.

Comment: You can use the INVOKE event and a custom URL SCHEME (yourappname://data-goes-here) to get the result. Here is an example: http://www.riaspace.com/2011/08/defining-custom-url-schemes-for-your-air-mobile-applications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are developing Air on Android, you may consider using an extension to do the job for you! checkout http://myappsnippet.com/qr-code-scanner-native-extension-adobe-air this is an AS3 library which uses the Zxing Java library and scans QR codes and returns the result back to your AS3 project.